# When selecting data with DATE_FORMAT() is not getting proper values MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string, datetime, where-clause

I'm having a table structure as below.

```
create table date_test (dt datetime);
```

insert statements :

```
insert into date_test values('2019-08-12');
insert into date_test values('2019-09-10');
insert into date_test values('2019-10-04');
insert into date_test values('2019-11-05');
insert into date_test values('2019-12-15');
insert into date_test values('2020-01-15');
insert into date_test values('2020-02-07');
insert into date_test values('2020-03-08');
insert into date_test values('2020-04-10');
insert into date_test values('2020-05-15');
insert into date_test values('2020-06-10');
insert into date_test values('2020-07-15');
insert into date_test values('2020-08-10');
insert into date_test values('2020-09-15');
```

when i select with below query I'm not getting the proper out.

```
SELECT * from date_test 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%d-%m-%Y') < DATE_FORMAT(SYSDATE()-INTERVAL 90 DAY,'%d-%m-%Y')
```

Output :

```
2019-08-12 00:00:00
2019-09-10 00:00:00
2019-10-04 00:00:00
2019-11-05 00:00:00
2019-12-15 00:00:00
2020-01-15 00:00:00
2020-02-07 00:00:00
2020-03-08 00:00:00
2020-04-10 00:00:00
2020-05-15 00:00:00
2020-06-10 00:00:00
2020-07-15 00:00:00
2020-08-10 00:00:00
2020-09-15 00:00:00
```

I need a data where dt values are less than 90 Days.
Can anyone suggest where to make changes.

Comment: Sorry, it's not so clear what you want to achieve. Please post desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things here I think. Basically you are turning the dates to strings in format `dd-mm-yyyy`, and the comparing the strings. This does not do what you want. Typically, string `31-12-2020` is greater than `01-01-2021`, (because the former starts with `3`, and the latter with `0`), while the corresponding dates compare the other way around.

You have a `datetime` column, so just use arithmetics:

```
where dt < current_date() - interval 90 day
```

On top of being correct, this is also much more efficient than performing conversions on the column being compared (eg: it may take advantage of an index on `dt`).

Comment: Yes, But what is the issue with that query where it is going wrong

Comment: @Kumar: I gave an example of what is wrong with the query in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use format in where statement. Use it in select section for format returned result like:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%d-%m-%Y') AS dt
FROM date_test 
WHERE dt < DATE_SUB(SYSDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY);
```

Look it in [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=2d6c7624ac684d58fddf10e962526642&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)